# Can we run EC2 instance locally - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know that few of AWS services can run locally(on my computer) so that AWS won't charge for development period, In the same way I want to know, Can I run EC2 instance locally so that it won't charge me for development period at least.

Comment: If you were running an EC2 instance locally, then I think we wouldn't call it EC2 anymore (maybe `ECyou` haha).  But...AWS certainly does have a free tier for most services, where you won't be charged for some period/amount of usage, e.g. no charges within the first year.  I have successfully launched an Android app on AWS paying almost nothing per month.

Comment: ECyou is nice :) , For Android App its okay but for EC2 it is little different, I think what @Jacob has answered would work in my case.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want to run in the local is the Amazon Linux image.

Yes, you can run it in your local virtual machine(VMware, virtual box, I.e)

> Step 1: Prepare the seed.isoBoot Image
>
> Step 2: Download the Amazon Linux 2 VM Image
>
> Step 3: Boot and Connect to Your New VM

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-2-virtual-machine.html

Comment: Great Sir, Let me look in to this and I'll come back to you.